# Associative array in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use an associative array (aka map) in my Google Apps Script. Is it possible? I was searching in documentation, but haven't found anything useful.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows little research, such as trying the code.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script is based off JavaScript, so you can use simple objects, like this:

```
х = {};
x.a = 'zzz';
x.b = 'xxx';
x.c = 'ccc';

y = {k1: 'x', k2: 'y', k3: 'c'};
y.k4 = y.k1 + y.k3;
```